# Power Automate Escape '@' character

Tags: power-automate

In Power Automate, I am using an HTTP activity with the following parameters:

```
Method: POST
Uri: Example.com
Body: 
{
   "Username":"MyName",
   "Password":"@mycode",
   "PrivateKey":"1234"
}
```

This request works fine in Postman, but in Power Automate, it returns an error which says `The power flow's logic app flow template was invalid. Unable to parse template language expression 'mycode': expected token 'LeftParenthesis' and actual 'EndOfData'.` Which seems to me like it's unable to read the "@" sign because the password is supposed to be @mycode, not mycode

Is there an escape character I can use for this? Unfortunately I'm not able to change the password.

Comment: It looks like changing it to "@@mycode" should do the trick -- https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Validation-Fails-when-field-has-Symbol/td-p/20588

Answer (score 3):

In Power Automate, special characters are always escpaed if you write them twice.
In your case it would look like this: `"@@mycode"`

Comment: I tested it successfully with single quote`'style=''width:'`

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise a variable and store your data in it later pass in "send http action".

‘Send http action’
[Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zueIa.png)

[Source video link](https://youtu.be/OvJL00em1rQ)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).